# JSF2 render retraining old values

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF2 with **@ViewScoped**

I have table listing, cliking on row opens record in disabled='true mode'
2- ON the popup in disabled view button called 'Edit'
3- When user clicks upon edit button, all fields on the form which are disabled will become enabled.

Problem is in disabled mode it is fine but when user clicks upon edit button it start displaying few values from old record which was being clicked.

It is not happening every time but randomly when you start clicking.

I am not reloading any data when user clicks upon edit button instead I only make `ajax` call and set `attrib` val to `true` and on the bases of that I render model values and it dispalys enabled values.

is it cache problem or any thing else ???
help required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bean set enableStatus =0;
and in edit button and all of your text fields, set `disabled="#{bean.enableStatus==0}"`
when u will click on edit then set `enableStatus = 1` in your action method and reRender it.
You will get what you want....

Comment: I changed it still facing the same problem, few fields getting rendered with old value.

Comment: set ajaxSingle="true" so that only this button will be rendered.

Comment: and remember to make clean and build and then deploy.  And once in sometime you should stop and restart your server whom you are working with.

Comment: I am using richfaces 4 so no ajaxSingle=true instead there is execute attrib. Yes i made change execute="@none" and it worked for me thanks for help